# How to: .NET MVC2 array of buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, button, controller, submit

I have something like this in my View

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ViewMasterPage.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MVC.ViewModels.EditViewModel>" %>
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%
        Html.EnableClientValidation();%>
    <%
        using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Edit", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myform" }))
        {%>
        <%for (int i = 0; i < Model.Activity.Count; ++i)
                            {%>
        <div class="editor-field">
        <%:Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Activity[i].SelectedActivity, Model.SelectListActivity)%>
         <input class="button" type="submit" value="<%:i%>" name="add_Button[<%:i%>]"/>
        </div>

    <%}
}
    %>
</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost, Authorize]
        public ActionResult Edit(string[] add_Button,  FormCollection collection)
```

When I go to my controller, only the button on index [0] is captured, why is that?
both `ICollection<string> add_Button and string[] add_Button` did not work for me.

In another word, How do you send array of button like this:

```
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="add_Button[0]" id="Submit3" />
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="add_Button[1]" id="Submit4" />
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="add_Button[2]" id="Submit5" />
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="add_Button[3]" id="Submit6" />
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="add_Button[4]" id="Submit7" />
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="add_Button[5]" id="Submit8" />
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make that DIV a FORM field to contain your inputs.

Secondly, to increment the value of i you need to make it say i++ instead of ++i.

Lastly, if you only want the buttons to repeat, you need to move the for loop around the button, not around the div and dropdownlist.

```
<% for (int i= 0; i < Model.Activity.Count; i++)
{ %>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="button[<%: i.ToString() %>]" id="Submit<%: i.ToString() %>" />
<% } %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks,
for "add_Button[<%: i.ToString() %>"), what about the ending "]"?

Comment: <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="add_Button[ <%:i %> ]"/>  like this ?

Comment: That is there. name="button[<%: i.ToString() %>]" you aren't quoting me correctly.

Don't put spaces between the square brackets and the <% because those spaces will appear in your attribute. Also don't forget the .ToString() on your integer variable. When using <%: it always expects an expression to return a value to be displayed.

Comment: You keep saying add_button but in the example of what you want it just says name="button... not name="add_button...

Comment: Hello, did what you said, no luck yet:(  can only capture button[0] and its value:"Add", button[1] button[2] are null when i click on them

Comment: Did you put your buttons in a form tag with the posturl set correctly? I am thinking your problem is different than I am understanding. Care to post the entire source of the view?

Comment: Hi, my post is updated. So just to be clear, each of add_Button does something for its corresponding activity. In my controller, I want to be able to determine which button I clicked and react to it

Comment: add .ToString() on your i variables on the button. <%: i.ToString() %>

Comment: And finally, the reason you are only getting one button to work is that each button needs to be in its own form. I will post another answer with all these corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Ok....I found something interesting.
My controller
`public ActionResult Edit(String[] add_Button, FormCollection collection)`

Any button that is clicked other than first one goes to FormCollection.

So If I click add_Button[1], it will actually go to collection["add_Button[1]"]

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here is my answer with your updated source.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ViewMasterPage.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MVC.ViewModels.EditViewModel>" %>
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%
        Html.EnableClientValidation();%>

        <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Activity.Count; i++)
        {%>

        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Edit", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myform" }))
        {%>
        <div class="editor-field">
        <%:Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Activity[i].SelectedActivity, Model.SelectListActivity)%>
         <input class="button" type="submit" value="<%: i.ToString() %>" name="add_Button[<%: i.ToString() %>]"/>
        </div>

    <%}
}
    %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I started a new project with just loop and buttons in there, still no luck:(.        All buttons except first one go to FormCollection["add_Button[1]"), ["add_Button[2]"] etc..    Controller with parameter IList<string> add_Button or string[] add_Button can only get add_Button[0] when clicked